# Django: how to convert string into form?

Tags: python, django

How can I convert string into Form?

in model you can just use this line.

```
model = apps.get_model(app_label='app_label', model_name='str_model')
```

I have 3 forms namely:

- Fund_customer
- Fund_employee
- Fund_supplier

and would like to do this.

```
type = "customer"
form = "Fund_"+type #that would make "Fund_customer"
form = apps.get_form(form) #I wonder if there's a function like this.
```

I just dont want to do ***if*** condition to achieve this.

Comment: Do you mean you want to make a form from a model object or just turn the string "cheese" into a form?...

Comment: Yes. I updated my header. sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django doesn't have a registry of form classes like it does for models.

The simplest solution is to make a dictionary with forms keyed by name

```
forms = {
    'customer': Fund_customer,
    'employee': Fund_employee,
    'supplier': Fund_supplier,
}
```

Then do a dictionary lookup to get the form class.

```
form_class = forms[form_type]
```

You need to remember to update the dictionary when you add a new form, but the advantage of this solution is that it is a lot simpler than creating a registry of form classes.

If all your forms are in the same forms.py module, you could try defining a function that uses `getattr`.

```
from myapp import forms

def get_form_class(form_type):
    class_name = 'Fund_%s' % form_type
    # third argument means it returns None by default instead of raising AttributeError
    return getattr(forms, class_name, None)
```

Comment: Thanks bro. Gonna use this instead.

Comment: There is the [`modelform_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function) function but I wasn't sure if this is what the OP was looking for

Comment: @sayse Yes, if the model forms are simple enough then you might be able to use `modelform_factory` instead of defining the form classes. Be careful to validate the model name though!